# Reading file with lists to list

Tags: python-2.7

I have a txt file:

```
['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
['ddd', 'eee', 'fff']
```

code:

```
with open(name.txt", 'r') as f:
    list = [line.strip() for line in f]
```

then I got "list":

```
["['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']", "['ddd', 'eee', 'fff']"]
```

and f.e. when I want to get the first element of the first list (list[0][0]) I got just character "a", not "aaa".
How can I change it? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to parse the strings into Python lists:

```
import ast
with open("name.txt", 'r') as f:
    data = [ast.literal_eval(line) for line in f]
```

then

```
In [148]: data
Out[148]: [['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'], ['ddd', 'eee', 'fff']]

In [149]: data[0][0]
Out[149]: 'aaa'
```